# Ratio Test Misunderstanding

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

As I understand, the ratio test checks for absolute convergence and absolute divergence. According to my math book, if the limit given by the Ratio test is greater than 1, then the series diverges. However, how can one determine whether a series diverges from only knowing about absolute divergence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The test says more than that. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\lvert a_{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert a_n\rvert}>1$, then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, because then you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.

Comment: But how? What if it alternates?

Comment: Can you check whether the answer above is incorrect then?

Comment: @Dude: all convergent series have a general term which tends to $0$.

Comment: @Dude156 The answer given above just explains that some convergent series do not converge absolutely. I don't think that it addresses your question.